# Как получить ID новой записи в MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Есть такая структура документа в MongoDB

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58f7d556aa52ce456672a67e"),
"created" : ISODate("2017-04-19T21:23:34.315Z"),
"context_task" : [
    {
        "task" : "напишем немного текста ",
        "status" : false,
        "_id" : ObjectId("58f7d559aa52ce456672a67f")
    }
],
"head" : {
    "userID" : "58f48037fc894e19a3f7b81b",
    "head_task" : "пробный забег "
},
"__v" : 0
}
```

Добавляю данные в context_task.task с помощью следующего запроса

```
task.update({"_id": req.body.id_project},
        {$push: {'context_task': {'task': req.body.input_task,'status': false}}},
        function (err) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            var body = req.body.id_project+","+req.body.input_task;
            res.status(200).send(body);
        });
```

Подскажите, как можно получить context_task._id новой записи после вставки? Пробовал в callback передавать второй параметр, но он возвращает только статус запроса

```
function (err, doc) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        console.log(doc); //output -> { n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1 }
        res.status(200).send();
    });
```

Comment: А update метод, случайно, не возвращает id записи?

Comment: @VladimirParfenov В доках написано что метод возвращает WriteResult - объект содержащий состояние операции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос был решен следующим образом:
Запрос добавления новой записи был переписан как подсказал @Сергей, и ID новой записи удалось получить с помощью

```
 Task.findOneAndUpdate({"_id": req.body.id_project},
            {$push: {'context_task': {'task': req.body.input_task,'status': false}}},{new: true},
            function (err, doc) {
                if (err) return next(err);
                console.log(doc.context_task[doc.context_task.length-1]._id);//получаем ID новой записи 
                res.status(200).send();
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Task.findOneAndUpdate({'...': ...}, {upsert: true}, function (err, doc) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('Error in Saving task: ' + err);
                        throw err;
                    }
                    console.log(doc);
});
```

Comment: Желательно объект модели называть с большой буквы по докам монги.

Comment: спасибо, в данном случаее возвращается весь док целиком но без новой записи, мне нужен id нового объекта в массиве. возможно вывод console.log(doc); происходить раньше записи, т.к в базу все корректно идет, подскажите как можно исправить или в какую сторону копать?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811510/mongoose-findoneandupdate-doesnt-return-updated-document

Используйте опцию {new: true}

Comment: Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос но я до сих пор не понимаю как вернуть именно _id новой записи, я могу с данного запроса получить весь массив результатов, а затем через еще один запрос выбирать _id или это как то проще можно сделать? Буду рад любому пинку :)

Comment: doc.context_task._id по логике, так, как к обычному ключу в массиве, можно так же и через ["_id"]

Answer (score 0):

```
task.update({"_id": req.body.id_project},
    {$push: {'context_task': {'task': req.body.input_task,'status': false}}},
    function (err, result) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        const currentId = result._id.toString()
    });
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]